# React to failed login in Windows, and launch an interactive window

Tags: windows, winapi

I need to place a link on the Windows home screen (before a user is logged in)

When this link is clicked, I want to launch a browser pointed at a specific web app.

This would be used to enable self-service password resets.

Is this possible? How would it be done?

EDIT: This must work on Windows 7 (and above) and Windows Server 2008 (and above)

Answer (score 3):

In earlier versions of Windows, you could write a GINA DLL, which could completely replace the interface that was displayed to users during the logon process.

However, beginning with Windows Vista, GINA was removed and support was added for Credential Providers. While they provide improvements over the GINA model used previously, they also limit the flexibility afforded to developers with GINA - gone are the days when you could display a custom interface.

This isn't to say that it's not possible to have a custom provider display some UI elements. But launching a full-blown web browser is a **horrible** idea, plain and simple, and just asking for trouble.

You may want to check out the article [Custom Login Experiences: Credential Providers in Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb648647%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is not fully up to date but is a good place to start from nonetheless.